# "Your flow finished" screen: can i have it removed?

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, admin

I am using [this app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMkfNUAT) as an easy way to add an unsubscribe link to emails send from SFDC. Everything works great but at the end of the unsubscribe process (which is a flow) I get the annoying screen saying "Your flow finished".

As I have another screen in the flow saying that the unsubscribe process went well, I tried avoiding the problem by hiding the footer on such screen, so the user wouldn't see the finish button and couldn't go further and therefore the flow finished screen would never be shown.

However, for some reason I don't really understand, the finish button still shows up.

So I had a look on the web and found [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5), which seems to be exactly what I need. But I don't really understand where to find this URL that should be edited.
I tried editing the flow properties but there's no option to edit such link.

Could someone show me the steps to achieve this? Or advise for another solution anyway?

Thanks!

EDIT: screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is my app! Excited to find it when I searched for "your flow finished." [So here's the solution I finally arrived at.](https://unhandledsunshine.com/2021/01/13/your-flow-finished/)
The flow  is launched by a visualforce page so I added a FinishLocation of a second VF page that confirms the person has unsubscribed. This replaces the 2nd screen in the Flow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uncheck the `Next or Finish` button under `Control Navigation`. That should do the trick.

Refer below image. See if this helps!

[image]

Comment: Turns out I can't uncheck both previous and finish. If I do that I get an error and the flow can't be activated. I don't need the previous button and I'd rather not show it either.
However the finish button keeps showing up even if I uncheck it. Please refer to screenshot in main thread

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: ConfirmationScreen (Screen) - You can set either allowFinish or allowBack to false, but not both.

Comment: Thats a valid error as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm). So suggest you to remove only Next/Finish button. If it is the only screen previous button would be automatically removed

Comment: It is not the only screen - there's one more before that. However, even if Next/Finish is unchecked and Previous is checked, the finish button keeps showing up as you can see in the screen I posted in the main question.

Comment: Are you calling this flow from visualforce page? If yes, does [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/f1uoll/your_flow_has_finished_screen_anyway_to_hide_it/) answer work for you? To specify finish location in the `flow:interview` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107834/discussion-between-hemant-jain-and-robruf).